# Private method 'method' is never used sonar-false violation by sonar

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I have sonar enabled for my code base. There was a violation Private method 'method' is never used. I have remove the method from code base but violation is still getting displayed. I go inside the file from sonar and it does not display the line. I am not sure why this is happening. I searched for this method in my entire work space still it is not present. Any idea why this is not getting resolved.

Comment: Have you reanalyzed since changing the code?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube and sonar java analyzer are you using ? Did you recompile your code in between analysis ?

Comment: Yes I am reanalyzing all other issue are getting resolved. Only this issue is still shown as not resolved.

Comment: I am using sonar 6.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a zombie issue. Please add any comment to the issue in the SonarQube - this will refresh the issue state.

Comment: What is this zombie issue? I have tried adding a comment still same issue. I have upgraded to sonar 6 still have the same issue.

Comment: Sometimes there are problems with es index. Some data are not synchronized, so e.g. issue on client side is open and close in database. When you add a comment, then data will be synchronized and it is should be closed.

Comment: I have tried re-indexing by deleting the contents of esfolder, i guess the issue is still open on database.